# Prove that it isn't possible to flatten a Teserract into 2-d space.

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

Its certainly possible to flatten a Teserract into 3-d space (see: [What does a flattened Teserract look like?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4446172/what-does-a-flattened-teserract-look-like)). But what about 2-d space? It doesn't seem possible without having some faces fall on top of each other. But can we prove this? Alternately, can someone draw out an unfolding with no overlapping faces and prove this conjecture wrong via counter example?

Comment: You could take one of those flattenings onto 3D space, and flatten it onto 2D space.

Comment: You won't be able to do that without having the faces overlap with each other.

Comment: You might think about why you can flatten a cube into 2-space, but not into 1-space.

Comment: The first net in the answer to the linked question could be unfolded without overlapping itself. You can "unwrap" the horizontal line of blocks, cutting along the top-right line, and unwrap the vertical line of blocks, cutting along the front-right edge. That won't overlap itself.

Comment: You could flatten the edges of a cube into a 1D space if you allow a "double edge" along the internal edges. It makes sense to double those since you're essentially doubling the outer edges of your net (there are 2 line segments of your net corresponding to the same edge of the cube).

Comment: @1Rock sorry, I don't see it. Can you please draw out what the unfolding would look like and add it an an answer if you have some time?

Comment: Note that all the cube boundaries are also faces that will need to be flattened.

Comment: Assuming I understand the question: A hypercube is topologically a $3$-sphere in Euclidean four-space, bounded by eight solid cubes. As the linked question shows, we can (cut and unfold and) embed all eight cubes in Euclidean three-space with enough of their incidence data preserved to get a connected object. By contrast, we cannot even embed one solid cube in the Euclidean plane. <> Unfortunately, I don't know a proof of this claim that doesn't effectively invoke [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).

Comment: In a typical 3D unfolding of a tesseract, most of the cube boudaries are duplicated. That is, in the original tesseract has $24$ squares that separate the cubes, and (except for the squares between cubes that remain attached in the unfolding) each of these squares appears in two different places in the unfolded cube. Do you want your 2D unfolding also to duplicate squares or do you want just one copy of each square from the original tesseract?

Comment: Just one copy of each square. It's like when we join two cubes, they "fuse" along the common face. I think it's still impossible to flatten without overlap.

Comment: Another approach is to show that the $1$ skeleton, $Q_4$ of the hypercube is not planar. There are various algorithms to check planarity of a graph. By Kuratowski's theorem, you could show it is not planar by demonstrating it has either $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ as a minor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the tesseract in four-dimensional Cartesian space
with vertices at $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ for all possible combinations of
$v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 \in \{0, 1\}.$
That is, it is a tesseract of side $1$ with edges parallel to the coordinate axes,
with one vertex at $(0,0,0,0)$ and the diagonally opposite vertex at $(1,1,1,1).$

The $24$ square faces of this tesseract can be unfolded as shown below.

[image]

In this figure each of the four vertices of each square is labeled with the coordinates of the vertex, although for readability of the figure the parentheses around the coordinates and the commas between coordinates have been omitted.

The red lines show where faces that happen to lie adjacent to each other in the unfolding are not connected along that edge in the original tesseract. The non-connection of these faces can also be deduced from their coordinates, but the red lines are meant to be a helpful reminder. In all other places where squares are adjacent along an edge, the squares are connected along that edge in the original tesseract as well.

I derived this unfolding from a fully connected diagram of a tesseract by simple observation, not by any clever algorithm. There are probably much neater, more symmetric unfoldings.

Comment: Wow, this is fascinating. Need a bit of time to confirm this. If so, the obvious question is how many unfoldings are possible.

Comment: Also, I'm having a hard time seeing how this could be actually flattened out from a Teserract. If flattening it were possible, then folding it back into one of the 3-d shapes the Teserract can become should also be possible. However, the long string of squares under the longer red-line can't really be "unflattened" into a 3-d structure as far as I can tell.

Comment: It doesn't come from a 3D unfolding. It is unfolded directly from the tesseract itself. The first four squares are a cycle around one cube, the last four squares are a band around the parallel cube, and the square in the middle is one of the faces between the two cubes. You can verify by the coordinates of the vertices, every square is a face of the tesseract, every face that claims to connect to another face actually does connect on the indicated edge, and no face is used more than once.

Comment: That's facinating. So, it isn't possible to unfold first into 3-d and then into 2-d but it is possible to unfold from 4-d directly into 2-d?

Comment: I don't know whether it's possible to unfold first into 3D and then into 2D. I haven't tried. I worked from a version of the "4D" picture in the linked question since that seemed to be a more direct method. Otherwise you have to guess which of the 261 3D unfoldings to use, then guess which of the duplicates of the faces to erase before you can unfold to 2D. It seemed more complicated that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to attempt an outline of a proof. Imagine two cubes that share a common face.

Claim: the only way to flatten this structure is along the common plane the two cubes share.

[image]

The reason is that if we take any other plane, we start with 3 faces making a T-shape (two bottom faces of the two cubes and the common boundary face). And this itself is impossible to flatten without overlap.

[image]

This means that if there are three cubes now where one pair share a common face along the x-y plane and the other pair share a common face (say) along the y-z plane, unfolding should become impossible. Which plane would you choose for unfolding onto?

Now, just look at all the unfoldings of the Teserract along 3-d space (see link in the question). In each of them, this configuration of three cubes where the common faces are orthogonal happens somewhere.

Hence, unfolding a Teserract to 2-d space without overlapping faces is impossible.

---

EDIT: This proof is incorrect. It actually is possible to unfold along the x-y plane (which contains the two unshaded faces) by moving the shaded face away when you unfold one of the cubes. I'm leaving it in to demonstrate the pitfall of this line of reasoning. And also because there is some hope if can be saved.

Comment: Indeed if you have three square faces all connected along one edge as in the second figure, you cannot unfold it into a plane except by cutting one square away so that it is no longer joined to an edge of any other square. But just as the unfolding of a cube requires cutting squares away from squares, the unfolding of the tesseract must allow cutting squares from squares. To end up with a connected net of squares it is not necessary for the third square to remain connected to the other two; it is only necessary for it to remain connected to a fourth square that is part of the net.

Comment: Note that if you want to transform a 3D unfolding to a 2D unfolding, you will have to cut some squares apart in order to unfold cubes, and you will have to erase some of the externally visible squares because they are duplicates of other visible squares (resulting from the separation of two adjacent cubes of the original tesseract).